# Pycharm's auto-completion not working properly

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm2017.3.3. I have statements:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
```

When I want to use the components of the `tfe`, Pycharm is not going to give me any hints. But `tf`'s auto-completion is working correctly.

I also tried the same two import statements using IPython3. And it turns out that all the components of `tfe` are correctly listed.

---

Pycharm screenshot:
[image]

IPython screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pycharm is doing everythings fine.

```
import tensoflow as tf
```

works ok because it has [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/__init__.py) and every reference exists there:

> `from tensorflow.python import *  # mostly this make it visible`

On the other hand [`tensorflow.contrib.eager`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager) does not contain any `__init__.py` file where you can find references.

And you should probably be doing import as this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe
```

Comment: It is ture. I found the eager's init file is empty. But why ipython still working fine? And is there any way to make pycharm give me hints.

Comment: @Microos even in tensorflow docs https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/run they imported module in nested view. I'm not sure that you should be using short version.

Comment: I have tried `from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe`, and Pycharm works fine. Guess I should keep using this import style. Thanks!

Comment: I found that whatever which import statement I am using, both the `tfe.__file__` is pointed to a same location: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/tfe.py`. I don't understand how `import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe` can end up with importing the correct `tfe.py`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Microos actually it's [import in `tesorflow.contrib.__init__.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py#L84) making this, maybe PyCharm get confused because there is a path that satisfy your import statement and also import at `contrib.__init__.py`